# Entity Framework CodeFirst delay experienced

Tags: c#, entity-framework, delay

I'm learning about Entity Framework and I am currently facing a problem where I take about 10 seconds to retrieve data from a database or to update a row, as if my code were actually stuck for a period of time, even though debugging it everything went normal.

The code itself, actually works as expected, besides this delay.

Searching on Google and here I did not found other people with this issue related to Entity Framework.

I think that maybe it's something to do with my `CodeFirstMySQLEntities` class constructor, but not sure.

If someone could provide me with a guidance, I would appreciate.

This is the main code:

```
namespace CodeFirstMySQL
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserRepository userRepository = new UserRepository();

            userRepository.Update("Klein", "OtherName");

            //delay experienced here

            Console.WriteLine("done");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the DbContext code:

```
namespace CodeFirstMySQL.Database
{
    public class CodeFirstMySQLEntities : DbContext
    {
        public CodeFirstMySQLEntities() : base("CodeFirstMySQLEntities") { }

        public DbSet<UserModel> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the UserModel code:

```
namespace CodeFirstMySQL.Database.Models
{
    public class UserModel
    {
        [Key, StringLength(100)]
        public string firstName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        public string lastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the repository code:

```
namespace CodeFirstMySQL.Database.Repositories
{
    public class UserRepository
    {
        public void Insert(UserModel user)
        {
            using (var context = new CodeFirstMySQLEntities())
            {
                context.Users.Add(user);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public void Delete(string firstName)
        {
            using (var context = new CodeFirstMySQLEntities())
            {
                UserModel user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.firstName == firstName);
                context.Users.Remove(user);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public void Update(string lastNameOld, string lastNameNew)
        {
            using (var context = new CodeFirstMySQLEntities())
            {
                UserModel user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.lastName == lastNameOld);
                user.lastName = lastNameNew;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public IList<UserModel> GetUsers()
        {
            using (var context = new CodeFirstMySQLEntities())
            {
                return context.Set<UserModel>().ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Connection String:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CodeFirstMySQLEntities" connectionString="Server=localhost; Database=CodeFirst; Uid=root; Pwd=" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Are you debugging locally to a remote instance of SQL Server?

Comment: No, as you can see the connection string points to `localhost`

Comment: Ah, yes, looked right on past that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The delay is almost certainly due to the time Entity Framework takes to fire up. You can confirm this by trying a second update before exiting your code.

[The following excerpt explains what is going on](http://vbfeeds.com/post.aspx?id=7511)

> Model Caching
>
> There is some cost involved in discovering the model, processing Data Annotations and applying fluent API configuration. To avoid incurring this cost every time a derived DbContext is instantiated the model is cached during the first initialization. The cached model is then re-used each time the same derived context is constructed in the same AppDomain.

Comment: Just tested and it actually is true. Going to accept your answer as soon as I can. On a real application what would be the best way to "initialize" DbContext? Just a random request?

Comment: It would largely depend on how it's hosted and the lifetime of the AppDomain. I believe there's an IIS setting to configure pools to initialise themselves and in a Windows Service (or any Windows Form app) you could do it on start up.