# A more efficient way of showing adds/deletes in a context

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am cloning user's information, security, departments and several other tables of information to create a new user with same setup. This information is being displayed through several DGV's. When I use a normal linq to context:

```
var x = (from ctx in context.UserInfo
         where ctx.UserID == userID
         select ctx);
```

The information display almost instantaneously, but does not display the added user, unless I call `SaveChanges()` which I'm trying not to do.

Then I switched to using local linq:

```
context.UserInfo.Load();
var x = (from ctx in context.UserInfo.Local
         where ctx.UserID == userID
         select ctx);
```

However, several tables I am querying have over 30k entries and the .Local call significantly slows down the process of displaying the information. From what I have researched this happens due to validation tracking.

Then I tried using the change tracker:

```
context.UserInfo.Load();
var x = (from ctx in context.ChangeTracker.Entries<UserInfo>()
         where ctx.Entity.UserID == userID && ctx.State == EntityState.Unchanged ||
            ctx.State == Entity.State.Added || ctx.State == EntityState.Modified
         select ctx.Entity)
```

This gave the same poor performance as the Local call.

Is there anyway to quickly display added objects and not display deleted objects without having to call Local or is there a way to speed up Local?

I have done a fair amount of research and worked on this problems for a few days, trying to figure it out on my own, but I'm going around in circles now.

I have thought about creating a copy of the context, before changes are made. Saving the changes as they happen, and if the user decides to cancel out the creation of the cloned user, calling up the original context and saving it, to restore the original context, but I would consider that a last resort.

The project is being done in C# .net 4.5 and Entity Framework 5.0 on a Windows Form

EDIT:

To give more code on how query's are implemented:

I have a loadData() method that initializes the data I will be using.

```
public void loadData()
{
    var x = (from ctx in context.UserInfo
             select ctx).ToList();
}
```

I believe this would do the same thing as the above code

```
public void loadData()
{
    context.UserInfo.load();
}
```

Then the query is called: This is fast query, but does not show context changes

```
public List<UserInfo> getUserInfo()
{
    var user = (from ctx in context.UserInfo
                where ctx.UserID == userID
                select ctx).ToList();

    return user;
}
```

This query is slow, but shows changes

```
public List<UserInfo> getUserInfo()
{
    var user = (from ctx in context.UserInfo.Local
                where ctx.UserID == userID
                select ctx).ToList();

    return user;
}
```

Comment: what happens prior to the code you've shown? Is any data getting read from the database? How are the new entities added? Have you tried calling `ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` at a relevant point in the code?

Comment: Have you thought about using EF instead? It will show you the added user without you having to do SaveCahnges() or load all the entities in advance.

Comment: All the information is located on a datalayer. The repository is loaded, context is set and then the query is executed. This all happens on the Form Load. I add Objects by context.UserInfo.add(user).

Comment: I've used dectect changes at several points, but for it to show everything load() has to be called on UserInfo.  I am using EF, or at least I thought I was. I have a .edmx that is populated by a SQL DB and the context is created from that model. I'm using EF 5.0 framework

Comment: Sorry , misread the question. In EF if you add an entity to the context it should be a returned in queries even before saving changes, no?

Comment: I haven't been able to. The only way I have been able to get an entity to show after its added is to load the local version of the context. From what I have read so far this is normal.

Comment: Yes , you are right. is this not good enough for you?Also , have you looked at the answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990618/querying-objects-after-addobject-before-savechanges

Comment: The problem with calling local is it takes up to 3 seconds to display all the information, which is not acceptable. I have looked at that. The 3rd code snippet is that type of method, though that link is using EF 4.0 which uses DBObject and 5.0 uses DBContext, so the EntityState calls are a little different.

Comment: Is it only the first call that takes 3 seconds? Try creating a 2nd context and doing the exact same thing again before exiting your code.

Comment: Each call is 3 seconds, the load up call is about 6 to 8 seconds. The second context takes the about the same amount of time, though the changes are not passed to it, which is to be expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally, I was unaware that ToList() acted the same way as Load(). With this I have altered my code to no longer use my loadData() method, but initialize only parts of the information I need.

```
public List<UserInfo>(int userID 1)
{
    var data = (from ctx in context.UserInfo
                where ctx.UserID == userID
                select ctx).ToList();

    List<UserInfo> user = (from ctx in context.UserInfo.Local
                           where ctx.UserID == userID
                           select ctx).ToList();

    return user;
}
```

This change has allowed my queries to run almost instantly and still track the Adds/Delete/Modifies within the context. The only downside I see in this method, is if a lot of objects are loaded into the UserInfo.Local it will begin to slow down, though in my case that will most likely not happen.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going for the long shot here - I think the delay is down the standard delay EF has on initialisation of the model cache. See [my answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507067/entity-framework-codefirst-delay-experienced/15507195#15507195) for more details. You'll need to modify your code to find out for sure ...

Comment: This is what I had assumed, in my testing and research. Though, I think I explained it poorly in my question.

"From what I have researched this happens due to validation tracking."

was suppose to encompass EF firing up and caching the mode, validating the associations and validity of relationship. Though this is only done in the .Local calls that I have seen. If I do not call the .Local the speed of my queries is almost instantaneous.

Which leads me to agree with your statement, though I want to know if there is anyway around this delay and still show the changes to the context.

Comment: I would expect a windows form to cache the model once is has been compiled. The first step must be to confirm that once compiled the rest of your system performs "correctly". Can you set up a dummy data read from `UserInfo` on application startup and then try your code?

Comment: Sure, am I correct in assuming a dummy data read, is loading and accessing UserInfo.Local on application startup, and then see how my DataGridViews react, if there is improved performance?

Comment: Do something like `var x = (from ctx in context.UserInfo where ctx.UserID == 1 select ctx).ToList()`. The `ToList()` ensures that a query is executed against the database and therefore the model is fully compiled. Wrap this code in a using `(var c = new YourContext())` keeping this context instance separate from the rest of the code.

Comment: Which of the above statements did you try? I believe the first one should work. The `Load()` before the other two is potentially dangerous as it effectively does `ToList()` (gets all the data) and the 3rd query has and's and or's without brackets. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbextensions.load(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: The first one loads almost instantly (without the local call). The second has same performance issue, I pulled the Load() off and put in a loadData() so the Load() or ToList() is only run once not each time the query is executed. Slightly increased performance but not enough. Third one added brackets with same changes as above. Slightly increase performance but not enough.

Comment: And no luck finding the entity that you added? It's also probably worth removing `ctx.State == EntityState.Unchanged` as you don't actually want the unchanged entities.

Comment: No luck unfortunately with the fast query. I need the unchanged state there, if they want to add a security protocol to a user, they need to see the original (unchanged) information. Edited original question to show a bit more realistic code.