# XML vs Entity framework reading speed

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework

i was wondering if reading xml data is faster than reading from DataBase ..
so I prepared a database Sql compact 4. and created a table that contains 10000 record ..
also I created an xml document containing the same 10000 elements.

and I decided to read them and compare the time taken for each one

so my code is as follow:

```
 protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int entTime = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;

        Database1Entities1 ent = new Database1Entities1();

        foreach (var item in ent.ttts)
        {

            string x = item.id.ToString(); 
        }

        entTime = DateTime.Now.Millisecond - entTime;
        lblEntity.Text = "Entity reading:  " + entTime.ToString();
       //----------------------------


        int xmlTime = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("/mydoc.xml"));

        foreach (var item in doc.Root.Elements())
        {
            string ss = item.Value;
        }


        xmlTime = DateTime.Now.Millisecond - xmlTime;

        lblXL.Text = "xml reading: " + xmlTime.ToString();
```

}

the result made me wondering ... did i go wrong somewhere???

in Milliseconds:

xml reading: 7

Entity reading: 117

---

xml reading: 5

Entity reading: 113

=================

so is it true that reading XML file is faster than reading Entity Framework ??

or my Data is not large enough??

your input is highly appreciated :)

EDIT :

I started using the stopwatch and the result is the same..

then I increased the record numbers in DB to 30000; also the xml file contains now 30000 record... the same result ..

then I applied the advice and made the reading loop 1000 time ... so code now looks like this:

```
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
         Database1Entities1 ent = new Database1Entities1();

        for (int z = 0; z < 1000; z++)
        {
            foreach (var item in ent.ttts)
            {

                string x = item.id.ToString();
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();

        lblEntity.Text = "Entity reading:  " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        //----------------------------
        sw.Reset();

        sw.Start();

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("/mydoc.xml"));
        for (int z = 0; z < 1000; z++)
        {
            foreach (var item in doc.Root.Elements())
            {
                string ss = item.Value;
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();

        lblXL.Text = "xml reading: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

and the result was confirmed three times as follow:

xml reading: 678

Entity reading: 8095

---

xml reading: 666

Entity reading: 73628

---

xml reading: 671

Entity reading: 73006

Comment: Your results seem inconclusive and unclear. Platform, disk hardware etc all matters. But yes, reading XML is probably faster in most cases. But now try a query or an update...

Comment: I found EF to be slow when the executable is set to Debug and within Visual Studio, but about x10 faster when set to release and running without/outside Visual Studio.

Comment: 10000 is very small..try with 1,00,000 records..

Comment: Be aware of the infamous slow start up time of Entity Framework - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507067/entity-framework-codefirst-delay-experienced/15507195#15507195

Comment: In the code above, you time the entity framework first and then the xml code.  Swap the order so that the xml code is executed first and see what the times are.  Also, perform the test many times in a loop, discarding the first few iterations.  This will eliminate the timing of the JIT compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not optimizing your EF query. You can turn off tracking, for starters. EF creates overhead for every single object read for tracking changes. If the query is only for reading data, you can turn off tracking to improve performance.

- [ObjectContext Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx)
- [DbContext Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853%28v=msdn.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

From my study, Entity framework is slow compared to all other storage mechanisms.  If you dont have specific requirements to go for database, you can use xml.

DataReader through ADO.NET will give better results too. DataSet option is like EF.